# (API) 405 Method Not Allowed on Laravel 7 with tymon/jwt-auth

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, jwt

So i'm going to begin with the problem.

I have frontend application that work with Bearer Token Authentication, which is send to my backend.

Everything with authentication is fine until i want to get my user data from my route

```
Route::get('api/auth/me','Backend\AuthController@me');
```

I get error 405 Method `GET` not allowed

Full Error Message:
`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file C:\Programming\LSUniverseCMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117`

I've already set my route to respond with `GET`

Here is my `api.php` file:

```
     <?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


     Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'api'], function ($router) {

        Route::post('login', 'Backend\AuthController@login')->name('login');
        Route::post('register', 'Backend\AuthController@register')->name('register');
        Route::post('refresh', 'Backend\AuthController@refresh')->name('refresh');
        Route::post('logout', 'Backend\AuthController@logout')->name('logout');
        Route::get('verify/{token}', 'Backend\VerificationController@verify')->name('verify');
        Route::get('me', 'Backend\AuthController@me')->name('me');

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'prefix' => 'user'], function ($router) {
    });
```

My `AuthController.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\UserVerification;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create instance of AuthController
     * Make middleware ignore login and register routes
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' =>['login','register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Register the user with requested credentials
     *
     * @param  mixed $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => ['required', 'min:4'],
            'email' => ['email', 'required', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'regex:/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/'],
            're_password' => ['required', 'same:password'],
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()->first()], 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
            'isAdmin' => 0,
            'balance' => 0.00,
            'verified' => 0,
        ]);

        if ($user) {
            UserVerification::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'token' => md5("$user->id $user->email" . sha1(time())),
            ]);

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Created'], 201);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed'], 400);

    }

    /**
     * Get JWT token via given credentials
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        $verified = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first()->verified;
        if ($verified == 1) {
            if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Not verified'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Return user information from database
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth('api')->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token)
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response;
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfuly']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh user token
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * respondWithToken
     *
     * @param  mixed $token
     * @return void
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
        ]);
    }

}
```

My route:list:

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name     | Action                                                     | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | api/auth/login          | login    | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AuthController@login          | api        |
|        | POST     | api/auth/logout         | logout   | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AuthController@logout         | api        |
|        |          |                         |          |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/auth/me             | me       | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AuthController@me             | api        |
|        |          |                         |          |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | POST     | api/auth/refresh        | refresh  | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AuthController@refresh        | api        |
|        |          |                         |          |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | POST     | api/auth/register       | register | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AuthController@register       | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/auth/verify/{token} | verify   | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\VerificationController@verify | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | {path?}                 |          | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

My URI Tab:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKLGu.png

So where's my mistake? Please help me i'm stuck with this maybe for more than 3 hours
I followed every step in tymondesign/jwt-auth documentation but don't work at all.

Comment: check php artisan route:list and uri in network tab to check if they are matched. finally clear cache php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: I've already tried that, still don't work

Comment: ok can you please share route:list and uri in network tab?

Comment: in bootstrap -> cache remove every file except .gitignore then run composer dump-autoload after that run composer update

Comment: @TEFO already tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem.
It's my mistake because i have typo in my `User.php` model

Model before change:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
        'verified', 'balance', 'isAdmin',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'verified',
    ];

    /**
     * getJWTCustomClaims
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * getJWTIdentifier
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }
    
    /**
     * RelationShip between user, and user activation token
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function verifyToken()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserVerification::class);
    }
}
```

Model after change:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
        'verified', 'balance', 'isAdmin',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'verified',
    ];

    /**
     * getJWTCustomClaims
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * getJWTIdentifier
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    
    /**
     * RelationShip between user, and user activation token
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function verifyToken()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserVerification::class);
    }
}
```

So i change `getJWTIdentifier()` return from `$this->key` to `$this->getKey()`